# JavaScript - Item doesn't get added to array

Tags: javascript

I've done a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wmpdigitalservices/vxa5mo14/). Some code below.

My expected output is

```
[{
    "support_advice": [{
            "id": "A",
            "type": "checkbox",
            "text": "",
            "value": "A"
        },
        {
            "id": "C",
            "type": "checkbox",
            "text": "",
            "value": "C"
        }
    ]
}]
```

However I get

```
[{
    "support_advice": [{
        "id": "C",
        "type": "checkbox",
        "text": "",
        "value": "C"
    }]
}]
```

I thought `result[elem[i].name] = matches;` would add another item rather than replace what's there already

**HTML**

```
<form id="rn_QuestionSubmit">
<input name="support_advice" id="A" type="checkbox" value="A" checked>
<input name="support_advice" id="B" type="checkbox" value="B">
<input name="support_advice" id="C" type="checkbox" value="C" checked>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var elem = document.getElementById('rn_QuestionSubmit').elements;

            var a = [];
            var result = {};

            for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
            {
                var matches = [];
                var item = {};
                item.id = elem[i].id;
                item.type = elem[i].type;
                if (elem[i].type === 'select-one') {
                    item.text = document.getElementById(elem[i].id).options[document.getElementById(elem[i].id).selectedIndex].text;
                }
                else {
                    item.text = '';
                }

                if (elem[i].type === 'radio' || elem[i].type === 'checkbox') {
                    if (document.getElementById(elem[i].id).checked) {

                        item.value = document.getElementById(elem[i].id).value;
                        matches.push(item);
                        result[elem[i].name] = matches;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    item.value = elem[i].value;
                    matches.push(item);
                    result[elem[i].name] = matches;
                }
            } 

            a.push(JSON.stringify(result));
            console.log('['+a.join(',') + ']');
            return('['+a.join(',') + ']');
```

Comment: Have you tried `result[elem[i].name].push(matches);`?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined(…)

Comment: if (result[elem[i].name]) {
       result[elem[i].name].push(matches);
      }
      else {
       result[elem[i].name] = matches;
      }

Comment: Actually use concat: `if (result[elem[i].name]) { result[elem[i].name] = result[elem[i].name].concat(matches); } else { result[elem[i].name] = matches; } `

Comment: This is happening because arrays are accessed by reference in js and you're passing it like it's by val.  the matches array seems useless in this set up.  why not just do result[elem[i].name] = [item];

Comment: That doesn't multiple elements with the same name - just the latest one

Comment: neither does your current set up  You reassign the value to a new array with one item in it every single time.

Comment: It does with @csp713 change - https://jsfiddle.net/wmpdigitalservices/vxa5mo14/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a lot of unneeded code could be cleaned up here...

```
var elem = document.getElementById('rn_QuestionSubmit').elements;

        var a = [];
        var result = {};

        for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
        {
            var element = elem[i];
            var item = {};
            item.id = element.id;
            item.type = element.type;
            if (element.type === 'select-one') {
                item.text = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
            }
            else {
                item.text = '';
            }

            if (element.type === 'radio' || element.type === 'checkbox') {
                if (element.checked) {
                    item.value = element.value;
                    if (result[element.name]) { result[element.name].push(item) } else { result[element.name] = [item]};
                }
            }
            else {
                item.value = elem[i].value;
                if (result[element.name]) { result[element.name].push(item) } else { result[element.name] = [item]};
            }
        } 

        a.push(JSON.stringify(result));
        console.log('['+a.join(',') + ']');
        return('['+a.join(',') + ']');
```

you need to actually decide to push or create a new array on each element.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0jhyj4wv/

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: result[element.name].push is not a function(…)

Comment: that shouldn't happen, you're missing a line somewhere important, check my edit and the working fiddle

Answer (score 1):

This is appening because you are assigning the `matches` array each time to the `support_advicce` property.

To make sure of what's happening you put this `console.log` in to your code:

```
console.log("before", result[elem[i].name]);
result[elem[i].name] = matches;
console.log("after", result[elem[i].name]);
```

And you will get:

1. `before undefined`
2. `after [0: {id: "A", type: "checkbox", text: "", value: "A"}]`
3. `before [0: {id: "A", type: "checkbox", text: "", value: "A"}]`
4. `after [0: {id: "C", type: "checkbox", text: "", value: "C"}]`

### Solution

Instead of

```
result[elem[i].name] = matches;
```

you could use (using ES6)

```
if(typeof result[elem[i].name] === "undefined") result[elem[i].name] = [];          
result[elem[i].name].push(...matches);
```